# Enforce specific value of one property from value of another with Typescript

Tags: typescript

Say one has a type, `A`, that describes three properties, `foo`, `bar`, and `fizz`. Say one also uses the usual `DeepReadonly<T>` to make all (recursively) props of `A` read-only:

```js
type DeepReadonly<T> =
  T extends (infer R)[] ? DeepReadonlyArray<R> :
  T extends Function ? T :
  T extends object ? DeepReadonlyObject<T> :
  T

interface DeepReadonlyArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<T>> {}

type DeepReadonlyObject<T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>
}

type MutableA<T extends number[] = number[]> = {
    foo: T
    bar: T[number]
    fizz: string
}

type A = DeepReadonly<MutableA>
```

Say one wants to create a *fully explicitly-typed* `A` (with the usual TS workaround, `createA<TA>`, to do this):

```js
const createA = <TA extends A>(a: TA): TA => a

const a = createA({
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: 1,
    fizz: 'buzz'
} as const)

// Test types to test full explicit typing of `createA`
type T0 = typeof a['foo'] // [1,2,3]
type T1 = typeof a['bar'] // 1
type T2 = typeof a['fizz'] // "buzz"
```

The question is, how does one modify this to make Typescript enforce the value of `bar` to be one of the values of `foo` (as the above `MutableA` is trying to but failing at). Ideally, it would be nice if the TS intellisense showed the allowed values of `bar` as one is entering a value for it. The solution should also preserve the *fully explicit-typed* result of `createA`

Comment: are you sure that you really need `readonly` for the argument of the function? Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpno7w) work for you?

Comment: @TobiasS. Ah, so for this, the generic of `createA` must capture all of the type information of the argument, such that `a` is fully explicitly typed. I've tried [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXQ0JN), but to no avail.

Comment: what is wrong with the solution I provided? Can you show an example where it is **not** working for you?

Comment: Apologies. I have added a bit more detail that tightens the question and explains why your solution is **not** working. Sorry for not being clear first time!